# fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@82dee0b9a1df/test/test-project.git/': Could not resolve host: 82dee0b9a1df

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have installed Gilab on docker container, now I am created the Gitlab CI pipeline. and the gitlab-runner is installed another instance, when I run the pipeline I am getting below error.

Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/var/lib/gitlab-runner/builds/hmKPWpWb/0/test/test-project'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@82dee0b9a1df/test/test-project.git/': Could not resolve host: 82dee0b9a1df

Answer (score 1):

On gitlab-runner instance,

Put `ip_address_of_gitlab_server 82dee0b9a1df` in `/etc/hosts` file.

And make sure you have exposed `neeeded_ports` outside container while building the gitlab container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in rancher and the same error happens just add the machine ip in the `/etc/hosts` file, like that:

`10.42.0.77             gitlab-b5f597f66-hcs96` 
`<pod internal ip>       <pod name>`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is correct, but i add this line "nameserver 8.8.8.8" in the file /etc/resolv.conf and worked for me. someone know if is valid this solution or not and why? 
 [here i finded this solution](https://bobcares.com/blog/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-ubuntu/)

Comment: This will use the public Google DNS server and if this helps, then mostly by accident and unrelated to the root cause of the problem.